# Sub windows that stay with all view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have an existing MVC application with three main views. 
My new task is i need a popup or a window or something that shows some statistic data and that windows always visible on top end of all view and user can still continue there work on the different views.

Kind of lIke a widget that always visible on ur screen no matter what you are doing on ur computer.

I need ideas/suggestion to implement this on my MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as a partial view.

In your Html code you can write something like this:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
  @Html.Action("Menu", "ControllerName", new { myParam="00" }); //last value can be null if you do not have any parameters.
  <h1>Welcome to the Index View</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

You should also make a controller for this menu, which returns a partial view.
This is aslo a cshtml page, which will be injected at the place where you call the @html.Action()

```
public class MyController {

  public ActionResult Menu() {
    var menu = GetMenuFromSomewhere();
      return PartialView(menu);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps. [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/) explains this more in depth.